# Weight gain diet for a Pescetarian?

Tags: diet, weightlifting, calories, bodybuilding, weight-gain

I was weight gaining/lifting about 5 years ago on a diet consisting of a lot of chicken, beef and tuna.

However, I stopped, and have since then stopped eating factory farmed meats, and now have a diet similar to a Pescetarian (Vegetarian + Fish)

I'm looking to get back into weight gaining/lifting with my new diet, but could do with some tips/links on a good diet routine to have.

I'm currently taking whey protein shakes (2 table scoops in one shake) per day.

However, I'm not finding my mass increasing, and I'm struggling to find a advice on a decent balanced diet for my requirements. I'm looking to intake 3500 calories a day.

Does anyone have any good tips/links on what I should be eating to achieve this?

Comment: Could you give more details on what is allowed in your diet and what your diet is currently like? What is your current situation--have you been lifting, and if so, how? Have you been trying and failing to gain weight?

Comment: @DaveLiepmann Thanks I've edited my question with a lot more info now!

Comment: Great updated question, Curt.

Comment: What's your weight, height, age, daily activity and exercise amount and goal?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

## The Short Answer

Vast quantities of fish, vast quantities of veggies. Vast quantities of milk if your pescetarianism allows dairy. Vast quantities of eggs if your pescetarianism allows eggs. Plenty of olive oil on the salads (and the eggs, and the veggies). Be careful of too much mercury in the fish.

## The Longer Answer

### Non-Factory Beef

If avoiding factory-farmed meat is your primary reason for eating veggies and fish, I suggest grass-fed, free-range beef. For one, grass-fed cows are practically a different animal from corn-fed cows, and the grass-fed nutritional profile of their meat and milk is much better.

I am very partial to meat shares for getting humane, non-factory meat. I get a quarter of a cow (enough to half-fill its own freezer), including ground beef and a wide variety of cuts (sirloin and kidneys and flank steaks and roasts...), all for a reasonable per-pound price. Split it with a friend or two if the up-front cost is too great, or if you don't have the freezer space.

### Non-Factory Milk

If you can find it, milk from non-factory/grass-fed cows is an awesome part of a mass-building diet. Milk is nutritionally dense and complete, and so adding a half-gallon to your three big meals is a simple way to add healthful calories.

### Maybe It's Not The Diet

Your issue might be diet, but it might also be that the exercises you do aren't ideal for adding mass. Compound exercises are usually better for adding mass than bodybuilding in many circumstances (see [this question](https://fitness.stackexchange.com/questions/3962/are-these-workout-routines-right-for-body-building/3963)). Your question is specific to pescetarianism, but you would find good general advice [here](https://fitness.stackexchange.com/questions/1631/how-can-i-gain-a-lot-of-weight-in-one-month). Don't forget to read up on [conflicting opinions of GOMAD](https://fitness.stackexchange.com/questions/3967/weight-gained-using-gomad-strategy).

On a side note, you're drinking your protein shake right after working out, [right](https://fitness.stackexchange.com/questions/4058/should-i-consume-protein-shakes-after-team-sport-cardio/4066)?

Comment: Is there any more advice you can give now my question has been updated?

Comment: Cheers! I'll look into getting Non-Factory Beef/Chicken to include in my diet. Where am I best to source this from? A local butcher? And yes I take protein shake straight after work out (2-3 times a week), and almost every lunch time, with milk.

Comment: Local butcher is good. Local farmer is best. Less-local farmer is good. Organic/health-food shops are OK.