# Is drinking extra milk a viable method for increasing my daily protein intake?

Tags: diet, protein

Can I increase my daily protein intake by drinking lots of milk? A friend drinks 2-3 liters a day and highly recommends it.

Comment: As a note to future users - This is not really on topic any more, as nutrition only questions are no longer on topic. This is borderline, as many people want to increase protein, however it should really be in the context of a fitness regimen, not just "How to get more protein".

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Milk **doesn't** have a lot of protein. For example, whole milk [is *49% fat*, *30% carbs* (sugar), and a measly *21% protein*.](http://nutritiondata.self.com/facts/dairy-and-egg-products/69/2) If you want to increase the protein intake then you want to eat protein rich foods such as:

- Lean meats
- Protein powder
- Egg whites
- Fish/Seafood
- Soy
- Greek yogurt

[Here are some protein sources](http://commonsensehealth.com/Diet-and-Nutrition/List_of_High_Protein_Foods.shtml); note not all of them are high protein but they do show you the calorie/carbs/fat breakdown.

The main reason a lot of people like to add milk is because it requires no cooking or preparation and it's easy to take in liquid calories. It can be part of a healthy diet but I wouldn't recommend drinking large quantities for reasons [outlined in this answer](https://fitness.stackexchange.com/questions/3967/weight-gained-using-gomad-strategy/4016#4016).

Also note, if you are trying to gain weight then protein isn't that relevant. Instead you should focus on increasing your calorie intake. Part of that increase WILL be protein, but keep in mind:

**More Protein != More Muscle**.

#### Why milk isn't a high protein food

<sub>*Taken from discussion below*</sub>

~12.6 cups of whole milk have [1839 calories, 100 grams of fat, 163 grams of sugar, and 100g](http://nutritiondata.self.com/facts/dairy-and-egg-products/69/2) protein. On the other hand, 380 grams of Tuna has [440 calories, 1g fat, 0g carbs, and 100 grams of protein](http://nutritiondata.self.com/facts/finfish-and-shellfish-products/4208/2). So yes, if you want to increase your protein intake, then you should eat a high protein food. I mean any food can become 'high protein' if you eat enough of it. Fun fact, [whole wheat bread](http://nutritiondata.self.com/facts/baked-products/4876/2) has the same protein % by weight, ergo whole wheat bread has gobs of protein. I know Mark Ripptoe is a cool guy and all but at one point math wins over dogma

Comment: 3L of milk = approx 12.6 cups = approx 100g protein. Is that not a significant portion of protein in a day?

Comment: ~12.6 cups of whole milk have 1839 calories, 100 grams of fat, 163 grams of sugar, and 100g protein. On the other hand, 380 grams of Tuna has 440 calories, 1g fat, 0g carbs, and 100 grams of protein. So yes, if you want to increase your _protein_ intake, then you should eat a high protein food. I mean any food can become 'high protein' if you eat enough of it. Fun fact, whole wheat bread has the same protein % by weight, ergo whole wheat bread has gobs of protein. I know Mark Ripptoe is a cool guy and all but at one point math wins over dogma.

Comment: I would add that last portion to your answer @Mike, because it seems a useful addition

Comment: I think we can disagree without calling each other dogmatic. :) Part of my point is that while you're technically correct in that milk isn't proportionally high-protein, this misses the point: milk is easier to add to a full diet than the equivalent weight of bread, or a pound of tuna. (You mentioned this.) Adding the milk to 3 big meals will increase protein (and caloric) intake to a sufficient level for almost anyone. And as you point out in the 2nd-to-last paragraph--that 1400 calories that milk has over tuna is important for gaining weight.

Comment: The question here is specifically about whether milk is a good way to increase protein intake. The answer is clearly: No. Is milk tasty? Is milk a good way to increase your calorie intake? Can milk be made into yogurts? Is milk a good source of calcium? These are all good questions and measures but none of them were asked here. I'm addressing specifically what is being asked. I already talked about why GOMAD is a bad idea for gaining weight [here](http://fitness.stackexchange.com/questions/3967/weight-gained-using-gomad-strategy/4016#4016)

Comment: Why did you choose whole milk for your argument? It's stating the obvious that whole milk has more fat and carbs than protein. Skim milk, on the other hand, is the opposite.

Comment: @JoJo Are you asking me or Dave? Skim milk is still 41% protein, a lot better than whole but I wouldn't count anything about ~60% protein as 'high protein'. Also 1 cup of skim milk has 12g of sugar and 9g of protein.

Comment: @mike I was talking to you. It's unfair to use the most fatty type of milk to represent all milk. That's like saying Hitler represents all Germans.

Comment: @JoJo I'm not going to respond to such an ignorant statement.

Comment: I agree that 2-3L of milk isn't ideal, but studies have shown benefit of drinking skim milk post workout. That shouldn't be ignored. http://biosingularity.com/2007/08/09/to-gain-muscle-and-lose-fat-drink-milk-study/

Answer (score 7):

The answer depends on what your overall goals are, and what you are doing with your training.  So, let's look at a couple of different people with different goals:

Jack is a marathon runner.  He runs for miles on end, and is into *endurance*.  Jack needs to keep his electrolytes up, make sure he has carbs for energy.  He still needs protein, but his muscles only need to be so strong, so his primary concern is *energy*.   On the surface it sounds like Jack would benefit from a whole lot of milk, but he really only needs enough protein to maintain the muscle he has.

Joe on the other hand is a power lifter.  Joe is taxing his muscles pretty hard, and constantly increasing weights.  Joe needs both a lot of protein and a lot of Calories because the process of building muscle burns more Calories than maintaining it.  Additionally, those muscles need the energy to lift the heavy weights.  There is also a very strong correlation between lifting heavier weights and more body weight.  This is why things like the [Wilks Coefficient](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wilks_Coefficient) exist, because a 140lb guy lifting 140lbs requires more effort than a 200lb guy lifting the same 140lb.  That and the process of lifting weights burns a *lot* of Calories in a relatively short time.  Joe is the guy who needs to be drinking lots of milk.

Now, please understand that when Mark Rippetoe or any other weightlifter is recommending GOMAD (Gallon of Milk a Day), they are not recommending it for more than a month or two at a time.  Drinking that much milk only works when you put in the effort at the gym.

For long term sources of protein, as a weightlifter, look at:

- Any kind of meat (red, white, fish, pork, etc.)
- Greek yogurts (high in protein, low in fat/carbs)
- Protein supplements (which refine the proteins found in milk and get rid of the lactose and other things people have problems with in milk)
- Soy (fairly complete protein profile, but acts like estrogen in high quantities)

The bottom line is be intelligent about what you eat and why.  Don't simply take someone's word for it, but find out the purpose behind the recommendation, the side effects, the time frame recommended, etc.

**Milk is not evil**, but it is not the end all and be all either.  When you are trying to gain weight, GOMAD (or the 2-3L a day) can be an effective means to do so--particularly if you have a hard time gaining weight.  It won't be all muscle, but it will be more muscle than fat if you are putting in work at the gym.  There will also be a fair amount of water retention.

**If you don't have problems gaining weight**, then no GOMAD is not what you want.  You want to control the rate of gaining weight so that it is mostly muscle.  Stick with regular food for your protein intake.

Answer (score 3):

Yes.  The strength training classic "Super Squats" recommends a gallon a day.  Milk is a great way to get protein and calories.  A couple caveats: A lot of milk might not agree with you.  (Might make you fart like crazy!)  It can also have a lot of sugar and calories so if you are really obese, I wouldn't recommend a lot of milk, but you can of course just drink skim.  Also, you might want to consider protein powders with milk instead of so much milk.  The gallon of milk idea kind of went away with the invention of protein powder.

Answer (score 2):

[Yes](https://fitness.stackexchange.com/questions/1631/how-can-i-gain-a-lot-of-weight-in-one-month). It's called [GOMAD](https://fitness.stackexchange.com/questions/3967/weight-gained-using-gomad-strategy) if it's a full gallon a day.

Milk is calorically dense, nutritionally awesome, has gobs of protein, and is simple.

Use whole milk.