# how to have big muscles for one who have been trying but have not seen any change?

Tags: muscle, weight-gain

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [I am underweight. How do I gain weight and muscle?](https://fitness.stackexchange.com/questions/6828/i-am-underweight-how-do-i-gain-weight-and-muscle)

Hey I am 15 years old and i am so underweight. I am 5 feet 7 inches and i am 100 pounds. I have tried everything. I have been working out in my home for like 2 years. And I have joined the gym and worked out for 3 months but now I am out. So how could I gain weight and what have i been doing wrong? Please help me.

Comment: How does your diet look like?

Comment: This question likely is a duplicate of [one](http://fitness.stackexchange.com/q/5065/3941) or [another](http://fitness.stackexchange.com/q/232/3941) or [another](http://fitness.stackexchange.com/q/1631/3941) question. Without further information specific to your case (what did you do at the gym, what are you eating) the answers to the other questions would be equally valid here as well.

Comment: [This answer](http://fitness.stackexchange.com/a/6836/1771) applies. For anything more specific you'll have to describe your workouts and diet.

Comment: Unless you have a medical condition you haven't mentioned, it's because you're not eating enough. Just eat a **lot** more. Whatever you're eating, eat twice that much, or just more constantly throughout the day. Keep going to the gym, so that your body uses that extra stuff for muscle building. Choose the right program for your level of training and goals (lots of other info around this site on that). Dave linked to a good answer.